# Django Haystack - unable to build solr schema

Tags: python, django, solr

I got following error when I tried to build solr schema:

```
(my_env) pecan@tux ~/Documents/Django/mysite $ python manage.py build_solr_schema
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/build_solr_schema.py", line 29, in handle
    schema_xml = self.build_template(using=using)
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/build_solr_schema.py", line 57, in build_template
    return t.render(c)
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 64, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 287, in make_context
    raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than Context.
```

Maybe these informations will be useful:

**mysite/settings.py** file:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '****'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

SITE_ID = 1

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'blog',
    'taggit',
    'haystack',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/blog'
    },
}
```

**blog/search_indexes.py** file:

```
from haystack import indexes
from .models import Post

class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().published.all()
```

**blog/templates/search/indexes/blog/post_text.txt** file:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.tags.all|join:", " }}
{{ object.body }}
```

I'm using Apache Solr 4.10.4, Python 3.4.5 and Django 1.11.5. When I tried to import haystack in Python console I was getting below error:

```
>>> import haystack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from haystack.constants import DEFAULT_ALIAS
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/constants.py", line 10, in <module>
    ID = getattr(settings, 'HAYSTACK_ID_FIELD', 'id')
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/pecan/Documents/Django/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting HAYSTACK_ID_FIELD, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.in Python console
```

I'm counting for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Haystack in my Django project was wrong. I used `django-haystack 2.6.1` package but it has a problem with django template context passing. This version passed in context a Context object instead of dictionary. More details: https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/pull/1504/commits/295584314e19a191a59450e053b21809adceca2a.

**haystack/management/commands/build_solr_schema.py** in `django-haystack 2.6.1`:

```
     content_field_name, fields = backend.build_schema(
         connections[using].get_unified_index().all_searchfields()
     )
     return Context({
         'content_field_name': content_field_name,
         'fields': fields,
         'default_operator': constants.DEFAULT_OPERATOR,
         'ID': constants.ID,
         'DJANGO_CT': constants.DJANGO_CT,
         'DJANGO_ID': constants.DJANGO_ID,
     })

 def build_template(self, using):
     t = loader.get_template('search_configuration/solr.xml')
```

**haystack/management/commands/build_solr_schema.py** in `django-haystack 2.7.dev0`:

```
     content_field_name, fields = backend.build_schema(
         connections[using].get_unified_index().all_searchfields()
     )

     return {
         'content_field_name': content_field_name,
         'fields': fields,
         'default_operator': constants.DEFAULT_OPERATOR,
         'ID': constants.ID,
         'DJANGO_CT': constants.DJANGO_CT,
         'DJANGO_ID': constants.DJANGO_ID,
     }

 def build_template(self, using):
     t = loader.get_template('search_configuration/solr.xml')
```

I had to uninstall django-haystack 2.6.1 and install a newer version using commands:

```
pip uninstall django-haystack
pip install django-haystack==2.7.dev0
```

I also solved import error. In this case I just added line `HAYSTACK_ID_FIELD = 1` to **settings.py** file and I set required environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to value `mysite.settings`.

I executed following commands after editing **settings.py**:

```
(my_env) pecan@tux ~/Documents/Django/mysite $ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="mysite.settings"
(my_env) pecan@tux ~/Documents/Django/mysite $ echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE 
mysite.settings
(my_env) pecan@tux ~/Documents/Django/mysite $ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE python
bash: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: command not found
(my_env) pecan@tux ~/Documents/Django/mysite $ python
Python 3.4.5 (default, Sep 17 2017, 18:19:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import haystack
>>>
```

Now `django-haystack` is working properly!

Answer (score 0):

**Debugging Haystack**

There are some common problems people run into when using Haystack for the first time.

**“No module named haystack.”**

*This problem usually occurs when first adding Haystack to your project.*

- Are you using the `haystack` directory within your `django-haystack`
  checkout/install?
- Is the `haystack` directory on your `PYTHONPATH`? Alternatively, is
  `haystack` symlinked into your project?
- Start a Django shell (`./manage.py shell`) and try `import haystack`. You
  may receive a different, more descriptive error message.
- Double-check to ensure you have no circular imports. (i.e. module A
  tries importing from module B which is trying to import from module
  A.)

**“No results found.” (On the web page)**

*Several issues can cause no results to be found. Most commonly it is either not running a `rebuild_index` to populate your index or having a blank `document=True` field, resulting in no content for the engine to search on.*

- Do you have a `search_indexes.py` located within an installed app?
- Do you have data in your database?
- Have you run a `./manage.py rebuild_index` to index all of your
  content?
- Try running `./manage.py rebuild_index -v2` for more verbose output to
  ensure data is being processed/inserted.
- Start a Django shell (`./manage.py shell`) and try:

> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>
> sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
>
> sqs.count()

- You should get back an integer > 0. If not, check the above and
  reindex.

> sqs[0] # Should get back a SearchResult object.
>
> sqs[0].id # Should get something back like 'myapp.mymodel.1'.
>
> sqs[0].text # ... or whatever your document=True field is.

- If you get back either `u''` or `None`, it means that your data isn’t
  making it into the main field that gets searched. You need to check
  that the field either has a template that uses the model data, a
  `model_attr` that pulls data directly from the model or a
  `prepare/prepare_FOO` method that populates the data at index time.
- Check the template for your search page and ensure it is looping over
  the results properly. Also ensure that it’s either accessing valid
  fields coming back from the search engine or that it’s trying to
  access the associated model via the `{{ result.object.foo }}` lookup.

Source : http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/toc.html

Comment: Sorry but this answer isn't helpful. I described how I solved this problem in my own answer.